# How to rollup multiple Java Maven project into one SonarQube project

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube

I have multiple, independent Java projects that I want to rollup logically into the same SonarQube project because the multiple independent Java projects all combine to make one application.  Is there a  I can configure in the POM files to specify the SonarQube project?  Or is there some configuration option in the SonarQube manve plugin which will do this?

Comment: If your projects are part of a multi-module maven project Sonar will treat them as a single project, no need to configure anything.

Comment: Note that [SonarQube Views plugin](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Views+Plugin) makes you able to aggregate results of different SonarQube projects.

Comment: Thank you for the comments, unfortunately neither of these are options